# For loop in c++ dll

Tags: c++, dll

I was making a verification system for my dll. I am just trying different things.
I used this

```
bool allow = false;
std::string Name = "Name";
std::string Allowed[] = {"ye", "lol"};
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Allowed); i++)
{
    if (Allowed[i] == Name)
    {
        allow = true;
    }
}
```

But the `for` in the for loop is an error.

I don't know why but it says `expected a decleration`

Comment: Where is `allow` defined?

Comment: Why not use `allow = std::end(Allowed) != std::find(std::begin(Allowed), std::end(Allowed), Name);` ?

Comment: It uses std::end and std::begin. I dont know rhat but i will try. But will it wirk too if i have more than 2 in allowed?

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `sizeOf` to `sizeof`
2. Declare allow

```
bool allow;
std::string Name = "Name";
std::string Allowed[] = {"ye", "lol"};
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Allowed); i++)
{
    if (Allowed[i] == Name)
    {
        allow = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what error, pls tell the error? @YoooOoOoOOOOOo

Comment: which line number you getting error? @YoooOoOoOOOOOo

Comment: @YoooOoOoOOOOOo try michael's answer

Comment: sizeof gives number of bytes so that will not work.

Comment: @AndersK yes I see!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
bool allow;
string Name = "ye";
string Allowed[] = {"ye", "lol"};

int size = sizeof(Allowed)/sizeof(Allowed[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (Allowed[i] == Name)
    {
        allow = true;
    }
}

cout << allow;
return 0;
```

Comment: Great answer! Might be worth adding how this fixes the original error.